# backgroung image is shrinking on ipad portrait view

Tags: css, ipad, background

I have set a background for a webpage and i have done it responsive by giving media queries.
I have made the size of background 175% for ipad on portrait mode, when I am checking the result on ipadpeek.com (please check the website [here](http://ipadpeek.com) once to see the original portrait mode background and landscape mode background )

For the resolutions of ipad, its looking fine on landscape mode and portrait modes, but on ipad itself on portrait mode, the background is not coming correct. It becomes small on portrait mode.   Here are the screen.

[This](http://pgdermatologos.com/perez-y-gavin-dermatologos/equipo-medico/lidiaperezperez/) is the url to my site.

[Here](https://plus.google.com/photos/112214378050471460118/albums/5902224159244543537/5902224157036436882?banner=pwa&pid=5902224157036436882&oid=112214378050471460118) is the screenshot of ipads portrait mode.

Please Help me if anyone can !
Many Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using `Background-size: 100% 100%`

Try using `background: cover;` This should allow the image to be aligned like it is on the webpage.

Comment: Hi sunny ! Thanks for the response !
On the landscape mode of the ipad the background image is coming correct but as i do the portrait mose , the backgroundimage becomes small ....
I have used media queries for the portrait mode of the ipad and i have to use 175% of the background with some positioning  , But i think on the portrait mode , its not taking the media queries , and taking the normal full webpage , thats why the background image is becoming small....
Please help if you can